# Selenium wrappers for Primefaces

Tags: java, selenium, primefaces

Is there any framework for selenium + PrimeFaces. I'm interested in having Element Wrapper pattern implementation for Primefaces.

regards

Answer (score 1):

PrimeFaces ShowCase has a suite of Selenium tests. Might be useful to take a look:
[PrimeFaces ShowCase](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/svn/examples/trunk/showcase/)

Comment: I found that, but it uses approach with clicking and selecting. I thought about having js based wrapper that is using js code to set the values instead of clicking. I run into several problems when using clicking approach and it's just beginning of my journey :).